# How to test Axios reject condition using Jest

Tags: vue.js, promise, vuejs2, jestjs, axios

I wrote a unit test for some Axios calls in my component. I verified the success path, where the call resolves successfully, but I am not able to verify the failure path, where the call rejects. How do I use mocks to verify this?

Here's a snippet of my `FetchImage.vue` component:

```js
methods: {
  preparedFetch() {
    axios.get(this.imageurl).then(result => {
      this.imageInformation.title = result.data.title;
      this.imageInformation.copyright = result.data.copyright;
      this.imageInformation.detailExplanation = result.data.explanation;
      this.imageInformation.date = result.data.date;
      this.imageInformation.urlinfo = result.data.url;
      this.resultArrived = true;
      this.$emit('imagefetched',this.imageInformation);
    })
    .catch( error => {
      this.errorMessage = "Information not found";
      this.resultArrived = true;
    });
  }
}
```

And my test for when the call rejects (for an invalid URL):

```js
describe('Invalid response',async () => {
  beforeEach(() => {
    axios.get.mockClear();
    axios.get.mockReturnValue(Promise.reject({}));
  });
  it('Invalid URL verfication', async () => {
    // Given
    const result = {
        errorMessage : "Information not found",
        resultArrived : true,
        fetchStatus : true
    };
    // Fetch the error result
    axios.get.mockReturnValue(Promise.resolve(result));
    const fetchwrapper = mount(FetchImage);
    fetchwrapper.vm.imageurl = "https://invalid.request.gov";
    fetchwrapper.vm.preparedFetch();
    await fetchwrapper.vm.$nextTick();
    // Validate the result
    expect(axios.get).not.toHaveBeenCalledWith('https://api.nasa.gov/planetary/apod?api_key=vME6LAMD7IhEiy7rDmjfIaG6MhiKbu1MNIqxtqd1');
    expect(axios.get).toHaveBeenCalledWith("https://invalid.request.gov");
    expect(axios.get).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
    expect(fetchwrapper.vm.errorMessage.length).not.toEqual(0);
    expect(fetchwrapper.vm.errorMessage).toBe("Information not found");
  });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Your `catch` block isn't running because the mock return value is using `Promise.resolve()` when it actually should be `Promise.reject()`:

```js
describe('Invalid response',async () => {
  it('Invalid URL verfication', async () => {
    // axios.get.mockReturnValue(Promise.resolve(result)); // DON'T DO THIS
    axios.get.mockReturnValue(Promise.reject(result));
  });
});
```